# TCP Client Socket is not getting listen to receiver thread

Tags: android, multithreading, sockets, tcp, bufferedreader

The below code is not able read data from the TCP server. I am not able to find the issue. Any help will be appreciated.

```
class Receive extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        while (true){
           StringBuilder log = new StringBuilder();
           String line = null;
           BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
           try {
              bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
           } catch (IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
           }

           if(bufferedReader!=null){
             while (true) {
                try {
                    if (!((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)) break;
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                log.append(line);
             }
             Log.d("==> ", "data is " + line);
          }
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: `(!((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null))` Twice a NOT makes it pretty unreadable. Please adapt for us normal coders.

Answer (score 0):

The outer loop is unnecessary and should be removed. But more importantly, you are breaking the inner loop only when `readLine()` returns a `null` string, and then you try to log that `null` afterwards.

Try this instead:

```java
class Receive extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        try {
            StringBuilder log = new StringBuilder();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                log.append(line);
            }
            Log.d("==> ", "data is " + log.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

That being said, note that this kind of code reads whole lines from the server until it disconnects your client.  Not all protocols are line-based, or disconnect after the server sends data.  If that is how your server acts, then so be it. But that would be unusual for a server to do.  Without knowing what kind of server you are actually connecting to, it is difficult to say if this kind of code should be used in the first place.

Comment: Thank You Remy Lebeau. Yes actually i am trying to connect to a rfid reader. That will be connected all time. So what the modification i can do in this code?

Comment: @BiplabDe that is entirely dependent on what kind of communication protocol the RFID reader actually uses. It is difficult to answer your question without that detail. Can you provide some documentation or example about what the RFID reader actually expects?

Comment: RFID is having some tag to scan , and it will emit the data over a network. And i have an android app to listen to it. 

socket = new Socket();
InetSocketAddress inetSocketAddress = new InetSocketAddress(strIP,nPort);
socket.connect(inetSocketAddress, 5000);
Using these code , i am able to connect inside a thread. And now i have another thread for receiving data from rfid reader.
And android app and rfid reader will be in the same network.

Comment: My goal is to build android app that listen to rfid reader on port 4196. and whenever tag scan happen , the android TCP client app have to read it and log it.

Comment: @BiplabDe that doesn’t answer my question. The RFID reader must format the scanned data in a particular way when it is transmitting the data. What is that format? The reader must delimit multiple scans in some way. What are the semantics the reader uses to communicate with interested clients? If you can’t answer that, then you can’t effectively communicate with the reader.

Comment: it generally send data like
<Buffer 00 00 54 45 4b 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 35 27 01 bf ff>.

This is i am getting in a client wrote in node.js

Comment: @BiplabDe that is not useful info by itself. Without knowing what that data represents, it is useless. Again, do you have ANY documentation on this? Or even the name of the RFID reader? There is just not enough detail to help you interact with this system correctly.

Comment: Thank you @Remy Lebeau. I am able to solve my issue. It was sending data in byte format. And it was Chinese rfid reader, that does not contains any documents or any manual. I have find it by trial and error.